# Convertir lista con distancia entre días datetime.timedelta(days en entero

Tags: python, lista, datetime

Quiero manipular una lista con Python que es la resultante de la operatoria entre otras dos listas provenientes de base mysql con fechas. La lista en cuestión es algo así:

```
[datetime.timedelta(days=13), datetime.timedelta(days=34), datetime.timedelta(days=5), datetime.timedelta(days=62), datetime.timedelta(days=60)]
```

Yo necesito guardar esos "13", "34", "5" etc y sólo eso para poder operacionalizarlos con otra lista pero que es de números enteros. Entiendo que debería ser algo relativamente simple, pero no consigo extraer los números como tales y los métodos que encontré son para pasar de datetime a str (y sólo con formato %dd, %mm, %y), no listas.

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia se las agradezco mucho

Comment: ¿podrías explicar el problema más general que queires resolver? Si trabajas con un objeto datetime, puedes usar luego sus atributos parar cada uno de esos valores: `ahora = datetime.datetime.now(); print(f'año: {ahora.year}, mes: {ahora.month}, día: {ahora.day}')`.

Comment: El problema era que recibía un objeto datetime como resultado de una resta entre dos fechas calendario y yo sólo quería utilizar ese resultado como número entero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes extraer el número de días de un objeto `timedelta` usando su campo `.days`, así:

```
t = datetime.timedelta(days=13)
print(t.days)

# Resultado: 13
```

Sin embargo un objeto `timedelta` tiene además campos para guardar segundos, microsegundos, etc. para poder almacenar cantidades que no sean días redondos.

Si es este tu caso, yo creo que el método más general será entonces usar la función `.total_seconds()` que te da el total de segundos (contando días y todo):

```
# Ejempo, un día y medio
t = datetime.timedelta(days=13, hours=12)
print(t.total_seconds())

# Resultado: 1166400.0
```

Si los datos con que tienes que operar vienen en días, siempre puedes convertir a días el resultado anterior, dividiendo por el número de segundos en un día:

```
# Ejempo, un día y medio
t = datetime.timedelta(days=13, hours=12)
print(t.total_seconds()/24/60/60)

# Resultado: 13.5
```

Para el caso de una lista, simplemente aplicas uno de los métodos anteriores a cada uno de los elementos de la lista. Puedes usar *comprensiones de listas* para una sintaxis más compacta. Por ejemplo, aplicando el primer método que extrae sólo los días a tu lista:

```
lista = [datetime.timedelta(days=13), datetime.timedelta(days=34), datetime.timedelta(days=5), datetime.timedelta(days=62), datetime.timedelta(days=60)]

dias = [d.days for d in lista]
print(dias)

# Resultado: [13, 34, 5, 62, 60]
```

Comment: El método para extraer sólo días aplicado a listas funcionó perfecto. Gracias